# How to implement DynamoDB in cURL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am working on a platform, which only supports cURL requests (only POST/GET/UPDATE, etc.). I need to use DynamoDB with my Application - is there any way to implement DynamoDB with cURL? More clearly, i just need to four things - `PutItem`, `Query`, `GetItem` & `Update Item` with DynamoDB.

I read somewhere about the 'Lambda' function, but couldn't exactly understand what's it's purpose in creating REST APIs. Will it help me in any way?

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Those libraries (SDK's) help you construct RESTful API requests.

Comment: Hi @jelly, Thanks for the answer! But can you please specify which one would help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS services in general are designed to be used with REST API's. All the AWS *clients* (aws cli, aws console, aws sdk's) are just wrappers for the services API's. To use DynamoDB with curl, you just need to understand the DynamoDB API and make the needed requests using cUrl. You can check the [DynamoDB API Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

You'll find more information about how to interact with the all AWS service API's in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/Welcome.html).

But there is a catch. And it is documented in the last link: All the requests that you will send to AWS API's must be signed requests using the [AWS V4 Signature Process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html). In summary, for your cUrl requests you will need to calculate the signature and send the correct headers like described in the process. If you use any aws sdk, or the console, or the aws cli you get that for free. But to use cUrl you will need to implement it manually.

You told us that your platform only supports cUrl. If that is the case, there is no other choice. But if it is a *nix based platform you can try to install the aws cli and use it instead of cUrl. This will make your life a lot easier: You won't need to implement the signature process and you also won't need to understand all the details of the API because aws cli wrap all of these for you.